# rounded window bottom corners

Tags: themes, gtk, metacity, borders

I'm editing a theme I increased the frame's top and bottom border-radius in metacity-theme.xml by doing :

```
<frame_geometry name="normal" title_scale="medium" rounded_top_left="8" rounded_top_right="8" rounded_bottom_left="8" rounded_bottom_right="8">
.... other stuff here
</frame_geometry>
```

and here what I get:

[image]

As you can see the problem is the frame's bottom corners aren't appearing, because they are overlapped by the inner window

I have tried modifying many things in the gtk.css file because it's the one that styles the title bar and inner window stuff ... but nothing!

how do I modify the border-radius for the inner-window ..

i do not think it is a gtk thing but a metacity think ... and maybe it could be solved using draw_ops ... but i have no idea

some info about the window manager i'm using:

```
_MUFFIN_VERSION = "3.6.0"
_GNOME_WM_KEYBINDINGS = "Muffin,Metacity"
_NET_WM_NAME = "Mutter (Muffin)"
```

Comment: What window manager are you using? Window manager version?

Comment: @muktupavels i updated the post for the info you asked